# ViewNavigator display top of application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, skinning, flex-mobile

I have a s:ViewNavigator component inside of s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication. Currently it shows up at the bottom. How can I make it display at the top of the app just below action bar? I looke though all related skins in the flex sdk but I found nothing relating to position.

P.S. this is a mobile app in Flash Builder 4.6

In s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication component:

```
var nav:ViewNavigator = new ViewNavigator();
nav.label = "Newest";
nav.firstView = HomeView;
nav.firstViewData = "recent";
nav.percentWidth = 100;
nav.percentHeight = 100;

this.addElement(nav);
nav.titleContent = [];
```

Changes in s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication Skin:
(Swapped if statements)
(changed y position of tabBar by 60)

```
if (contentGroup.includeInLayout)
        {
            var contentGroupHeight:Number = (_isOverlay) ? unscaledHeight : Math.max(unscaledHeight - tabBarHeight, 0);
            contentGroup.setLayoutBoundsSize(unscaledWidth, contentGroupHeight);
            contentGroup.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, 0);
        }
        if (tabBar.includeInLayout)
        {
            tabBarHeight = Math.min(tabBar.getPreferredBoundsHeight(), unscaledHeight);
            tabBar.setLayoutBoundsSize(unscaledWidth, tabBarHeight);
            tabBar.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, 60); //unscaledHeight - tabBarHeight
            tabBarHeight = tabBar.getLayoutBoundsHeight(); 

            // backgroundAlpha is not a declared style on ButtonBar
            // TabbedViewNavigatorButtonBarSkin implements for overlay support
            var backgroundAlpha:Number = (_isOverlay) ? 0.75 : 1;
            tabBar.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", backgroundAlpha);
        }
```

Changes in ViewNavigator Skin:

(took away (-) contentGroupPosition from contentGroupHeight)

(multiplied contentGroupPosition by 2 so that other elements in the app would not be below the buttonBar. Action bar and buttonBar will have to be same size for this to work properly and There is no way to access the height of the button bar itself from vieNavigator skin as far as I can tell)

```
if (contentGroup.includeInLayout)
        {
            // If the hostComponent is in overlay mode, the contentGroup extends
            // the entire bounds of the navigator and the alpha for the action 
            // bar changes
            // If this changes, also update validateEstimatedSizesOfChild
            var contentGroupHeight:Number = (_isOverlay) ? unscaledHeight : Math.max(unscaledHeight - actionBarHeight, 0);
            var contentGroupPosition:Number = (_isOverlay) ? 0 : actionBarHeight;

            contentGroup.setLayoutBoundsSize(unscaledWidth, contentGroupHeight-contentGroupPosition);
            contentGroup.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, contentGroupPosition*2);
        }
```

Comment: Please share your code.  If you have created your own ViewNavigator component as a child of TabbedViewNavigatorApplication it is up to you to position it.  Whether that is in a custom skin you create or in an 'old school' single MXML component is dependent upon your implementation.

Comment: At a time I had no code as I was unable to find any reference to position or size. Now I edited skins and got it working but it feels like an ugly hack. Can you see a better way from the code in the updated question?